# Cisco auto smartport - description removal

Tags: cisco

let me preface by saying I have zero experience with macros and auto smartports. But, all I'm looking to do is when a port goes down, the interface description gets removed, is that possible and if so, what is the cli coding? Thanks for any help!

I did type this in after googling for a while, but it does nothing:

```
macro auto execute REMOVE_INT_DESC  {
 if [[ $LINKUP == NO ]]
  then conf t
  interface  $INTERFACE
  no description
  exit
  end
 fi
}
!
macro auto mac-address-group REMOVE_INT_DESC
 oui list 94B40F
macro auto global processing
```